# New Variable Across Files

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to build a system where you type parameters into an html form and that creates a different variable in a different js file. The way it would work is there would be a “main.js” file which processed what happens when the form is submitted, then it would create a new variable and put it in the “var.js” file. Is this possible?

Comment: possible: yes. recommended: no.

Comment: Not as described.  You'll need to use localStorage or a serverside database; web pages can't permanently modify their own source code or otherwise touch the filesystem.

Comment: A variable is not created in a file, it is created in an execution environment. What do you really want to do, modify script files on the server?